# ListView onClick() causes my app to force close

Tags: java, android

I am trying to setup a onclick listener on a listview items which is populated from an external database in assets folder.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
    databaseAccess.open();
    List<String> quotes = databaseAccess.getStaffs();
    databaseAccess.close();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, quotes);
    this.listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

                //int pos = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Cursor c=  (Cursor)listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DetailsView.class);

                intent.putExtra("Name", c.getString(1));
                //intent.putExtra("Address", getString(2));
                //intent.putExtra("Name", pos);
                //intent.putExtra("Address", pos+1);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
}
```

**DatabaseOpenHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "quotes.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

**DatabaseAccess**

```
public class DatabaseAccess {

private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private static DatabaseAccess instance;

// private constructor ro avoid object creation from outside classes
private DatabaseAccess(Context context) {
    this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
}

// return a singleton instance of DatabaseAccess
public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DatabaseAccess(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

// open the database connection
public void open() {
    this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

// close the database connection
public void close() {
    this.database.close();
}

// read all quotes from the database
public List<String> getQuotes() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM LEMONICEKING", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        list.add(cursor.getString(0));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}

public List<String> getStaffs() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Staffs", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        list.add(cursor.getString(1));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}
```

**DetailsView.java**

```
public class DetailsView extends AppCompatActivity {
    String Name ;
    String Address;

    private TextView tvName;
    private TextView tvAddress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.details_view);

    Name =this.getIntent().getStringExtra("Name");
    //Address =this.getIntent().getStringExtra("Address");

    tvName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
    tvAddress =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);

    tvName.setText(Name);
    //tvAddress.setText(Address);

    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.cindymichalowski.externaldatabasedemo.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

**details_view.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dip" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:textSize="25dip"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dip" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:textSize="25dip"/>
```

What's is wrong with my code? I tried putextra intent but when i click listview item the app force close.

Comment: Here is my project shared on mediafire

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/gkreqx7yd1gtjq9/ExternalDatabaseDemo.zip/file

Comment: Can you add your error log?

Comment: Maybe you can write `String name = quotes.get(position)` in onitemclicklistener and you can pass name via extra intent.

Comment: is detailsview.class looks good?